# com exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, copy, worksheet

I write a c# program for copy sheet. I got the exception error(0x800A03EC) when I call [WorkSheet.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method until 105 times.
This is my snippet code:  using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

```
private void CreateSheet(string dst_fileName)
{
    object cell1 = "A2";

    ApplicationClass app = null;
    Workbook book = null;
    Worksheet sheet = null;
    Worksheet sheet_to_copy = null;
    int i=0;

    try
    {
        app = new ApplicationClass();
        app.Visible = false;
        app.ScreenUpdating = false;
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;

        book = app.Workbooks.Open(dst_fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", true,
                                  XlPlatform.xlWindows,
                                  "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        // Reference to the worksheet
        sheet_to_copy = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

        for(;i<listViewPrg.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[book.Worksheets.Count];
            // Copy the worksheet to the end of the worksheets
            sheet_to_copy.Copy(Missing.Value, sheet);
            sheet.Name = "NewSheet(" + book.Worksheets.Count + ")";
        }
        book.SaveAs(dst_fileName, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        QuitExcel(app);
    }
}
```

I can't found any solution about this. Could someone give me a hint to solve this problem?
Thank you so much.

Comment: If at first you fail, call it again... 105 times... have you looked up that HRESULT in the context of the interface you're using to see what error it indicates?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have some corrupted Excel registry entries or so?

Why don't you try to use an open source reader of excel files and do everything using them? The speed would skyrocket and i guarantee you would not get these errors!